# Auth user check role is not working in serviceProvider Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, roles, service-provider, laravel-permission

when i use (auth()->user()->hasRole('User')) or (Auth::user()->hasRole('User')) in service provider it gives me this error:

```
Call to a member function hasRole() on null
```

I use spatie library and include this in my serviceProvider file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
```

and the code I write is:

```
if (Auth::user()->hasRole('User')) {
    $count = Complaint::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('is_deleted', 'not_deleted')->get()->count();
} else {
    $count = Complaint::where('status', '!=', null)->where('is_deleted', 'not_deleted')->get()->count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Laravel session is initialized in the middleware so you can't access Auth::... from a Service Provider because they are executed before the middleware in the request lifecycle.